# Weblogic 9 from 32 to 64 bit : speed issues, is tuning GC the answer?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, weblogic9.x

For 6 months now we are running in parrallel multiple instances of WebLogic 9 servers. 10 JVMs in total, 5 on the "old" 32 bit Windows servers and 5 on our new 64 bit Windows servers.

We moved from 32 to 64 bit to address the heap issue problems we faced, our WebLogic application servers would be busting 1.2 or 1.3g of RAM multiple times a day when we had a big users peek.

Now the global comment is, while the applications are no longer crashing due to lack of memory, the whole thing is slower in 64bit than in 32 bit.

We are using  : Weblogic 9
Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1
Java : jdk1.5.0_22

Here are the mem args parameter currently used : set MEM_ARGS=-Xms6144m -Xmx12288m

Now I noticed that setting the -Xmn parameter to 1024m would

like : set MEM_ARGS=-Xms6144m -Xmx12288m -Xmn1024m

I cannot run real stress tests right now and simulate a big workload quickly. I do however noticed that the memory used by the process is quite lower with this -Xmn parameter.

In the end I want to know.

Is there anything I can do regarding the mem args and/or specifically the -Xmn for garbage collection to improve the speed?

Thanks